# Date Time Clarification

Tags: java

Currently I have a AIX SERVER and if I issue the command `date` on the terminal, I get the response as `Mon Nov  4 00:28:40 EST 2013`.

And I have the seconds value 1383561560 which is the number of seconds since `Wednesday, 31 December 1969, 19:00:00 (UTC time)`.

Now I have a code which computes the date and time since  `31 December 1969, 19:00:00 (UTC time)` to EST time.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy_HH:mm:ss a");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
long ms = (long)(1383560920) *1000;
Date d1 = new Date(ms);
String formattedDate = df.format(d1); 
System.out.println("Now the date/time is "+formattedDate );
```

Now the date/time displayed is `11/04/2013_05:28:40 AM`

Here why is there a 5 hour difference?

Comment: Because there are 5 hours of difference between EST and UTC at time zone, but they both represent the same instant in time. EST is UTC - 5. Refer to [Eastern Time Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone)

Comment: By the way, this **is not** a Java problem, it may happen in other programming languages as well.

Comment: But in my code I'm converting to EST timezone right so shouldn't the java code take care of the conversion.

Comment: It's doing it. If you change `df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")); to `df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` you'll get the *expected* answer.

Comment: I changed it to `UTC` and I got `11/04/2013_10:28:40 AM`. How come 10 hours got added where the expected time was `11/04/2013_00:28:40 AM`.

Comment: Daylight savings also sometimes come into the picture ... You should go through http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/dst-faq-138158.html it gives very good insight to timezones related queries in java

Comment: But for NOV month daylight savings time don't apply right.

Answer (score 1):

Java `Date` base time start from `1 January 1970, 00:00:00` but your time is `31 December 1969, 19:00:00`. So the difference of calculated time will be  5 hour.

For details, read this [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29).

> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified
>   number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the
>   epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
>
> **Parameters:** date - the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.